# How to create a remote display by passing the data for each object in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#

I have a program that displays data coming from the serial port in a number of TextBox's that also change colour based on the values and I want to create a remote of this on another PC on the same network. Is it possible to pass the TextBox object data over the TCP link and somehow write this back to the remote TextBox? I could of course just pass the serial data but I would also need to process this and ensure that the remote has the same scaling/offsets etc. Passing the TextBox object parameters seems like a neater solution, if at all possible.